# How can I get the data from my c# class to ajax success?

Tags: c#, ajax, visual-studio

I'm having trouble on getting the data from my c# class , on visual studio debugger I received the data but It's not returning it to my controller class
here's my ajax function

```
let GetRecord = () => {
    var elemEmployee = 55;

    var startDT = $('#searchFilterStartDate').val();
    var endDT = $('#searchFilterEndDate').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Modules/GetDTRRecord",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            EmployeeID: elemEmployee,
            DateFrom: endDT,
            DateTo: startDT,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {




             console.log(data);


        }
    });
}
```

here's my controller snippet

```
public List<EmployeeDTRRecordList.Entity> GetDTRRecord(EmployeeDTRRecordList.Entity data)
        {
            var entity = new EmployeeDTRRecordList();
            return entity.GetData(data);
        }
```

snippet from my c# class, where Data Fetch method performs sql transaction using procedures and it succesfully received data back to entity.

```
public List<Entity>GetData(Entity entity)
        {
            DataFetch(entity);
            return ToEntityList();
        }
```

but I can't can't received it on my ajax call, my console.log is empty

Comment: In the browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, what is the response body from the server in the AJAX call?  If it doesn't contain the data you expect then it sounds like the server-side code isn't getting/returning the data you expect.  If you debug the server-side code and store the result of `entity.GetData(data)` in a variable before returning it, what does that variable contain?

Comment: Try making the controller action an  ActionResult<EmployeeDTRRecordList.Entity>